# How tohandle user statuses

Tags: php, user-controls

At the moment I have User entity with predefined statuses as constants. User has STATUS_NOT_CONFIRMED by default.

```
interface UserInterface
{
   const STATUS_ENABLED  = 1;
   const STATUS_DISABLED = 2;
   const STATUS_BANNED   = 3;
   const STATUS_NOT_CONFIRMED = 4;
}
```

But I'm stuck with a question of **what the best (or better) way to manage User statuses**:

- using just one method like $user->changeStatusTo($status) which is similar to $user->setStatus($status);
- create methods like $user->enable(), $user->disable(), $user->ban() which is more eloquent but can lead to the problem if I have more statuses in the future;

I'll glad to see any answers and advices, thanks!

Comment: As of me, the first option is better than the 2nd one. Use one method to set the status so that it can handle dynamic number of status in your application. Maintenance would be more easier with the first option.

Comment: I prefer 2nd way, you can put changeStatus as private function in user, but the user should have specific actions with no parameters

Comment: @4EACH Thanks for your reply. Could you explain, please, why you prefer the 2nd option to the 1st one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create both variants and let them call each other. So calling `ban` would call `setStatus`. If you later add new statuses, you could extend setStatus and if really needed, add a new method.

For convinience reasons, I would also extend the `UserInterface` interface to save the *max* value. That way, you could change the interface without touching your `setStatus` method.

```
interface UserInterface
{
   const STATUS_ENABLED  = 1;
   const STATUS_DISABLED = 2;
   const STATUS_BANNED   = 3;
   const STATUS_NOT_CONFIRMED = 4;

   const STATUS_MAX = self::STATUS_NOT_CONFIRMED;
}

class User implements UserInterface {

    // ...
    function setStatus($status) {
        if ($status < 0 || $status > UserInterface::STATUS_MAX) {
            throw InvalidArgumentException('status');
        }
        $this->status = $status;
    }

    function ban() {
        $this->setStatus(UserInterface::STATUS_BAN);
    }
    // ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I like it. 
I just thought: if I create the UserService class that will handle operations over User entity. It will have methods like $userService->banUser($userId) and etc. And user will only have the setStatus(..) method as you described above. What do you think about it?

Comment: Creating a UserService to achieve this imho only make sense, if the user model currently don't know, how to store his own data and you have to call some external classes for persistence. If you need an external class for persistence and setStatus actually calls the UserService, than I see no problem. You shouldn't spread persistence logic for a single model over multiple classes, otherwise you run into problems, if something changes

Comment: My model doesn't know anything about persistence, I use doctrine for persistence stuff. 
I mean using UserService that contains methods enable(), disable() and ban(). And those methods will call setStatus(..) of User model.
Example in UserService: function banUser($userId) { $user = $this->userRepo->find($userId); $user->setStatus(BANNED) };

Comment: @Shandur then I would go for `$user = $userSerice->getUser($id); $user->ban();` as I dont see a benefit of doing this in the user service

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest to use magic method __get() with userInterface and check constant dynamically in below way

```
<?php

interface UserInterface
{
   const STATUS_ENABLE  = 1;
   const STATUS_DISABLE = 2;
   const STATUS_BAN = 3;
   const STATUS_NOT_CONFIRM = 4;
   const STATUS_DEFAULT = self::STATUS_NOT_CONFIRM;
}

class User implements UserInterface{
    public $status = UserInterface::STATUS_DEFAULT;
    private function setStatus($status) {
        if ($status < 0 || $status > UserInterface::STATUS_DEFAULT) {
            throw InvalidArgumentException('status');
        }
        $this->status = $status;
    }
    public function getStatus() {
        return $this->status;
    }

    function __call($fn_name,$args)
    {
        if(strpos($fn_name,'make')==0)
        {
            $statusChangeTo = "STATUS_".strtoupper(substr($fn_name,4));
            $constant= 'UserInterface::'.$statusChangeTo;
            if(defined($constant))
            {
                $this->setStatus(constant($constant));
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Invalid method ".$fn_name);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid method ".$fn_name);
        }
    }

}
$user= new User();
var_dump($user->getStatus());
$user->makeBan();
var_dump($user->getStatus());
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I don't like the way with using magic methods

Comment: @Shandur without using magic method there is no way to implement dynamic function for dynamic statuses